# Proof gcd( n!+1, (n+1)!+1 ) = 1

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm

Is there anybody who knows how to solve the following?

Qn1: Show that for any integer n ≥ 0, one has
gcd( n!+1, (n+1)!+1 ) = 1

Qn2 :Why is it that the greatest common divisor of any two integers a,b∈Z is defined as the unique non-negative integer gcd(a,b)∈Z, where Z is ≥ 0 such that: 
{ar + bs ∈ Z : r,s∈Z} = gcd(a,b)*Z

Comment: Any common divisor is a divisor of the difference, $(n+1)!-n!=n\cdot n!$.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why one shouldn't ask two questions in one question. Your first question has been answered in the above Q&A. Also, what have you tried to solve the second question? Do you know Bézout's lemma?

Comment: I'm not too sure about Bézout's lemma you mentioned

Comment: What do you mean by " gcd(a,b)∈Z, where Z is ≥ 0"?